# CMakeLists.txt that covers 32-bit Linux, 64-bit Linux and 32-bit Windows

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt, cmake, 32bit-64bit

How do I make a C++ CMake project that works in this way?

1. All build intermediate products and binaries will be separated into 2 folders, one for 32-bit and the other for 64-bit. The names of the binaries will be the same for 32-bit and 64-bit.
2. If my current platform is 32-bit Linux or non-Linux (e.g. Windows), then build only 32-bit.
3. If my current platform is 64-bit Linux, then build for both 32-bit and 64-bit.
4. If my current platform is 32-bit Linux, then CPack will produce Debian and TGZ packages only for the 32-bit binaries.
5. If my current platform is 64-bit Linux, then CPack will produce Debian and TGZ packages for both the 32-bit and 64-bit binaries.
6. The program depends on sqlite3 and Qt4.

By the way, for Windows, I'm currently generating setup packages using InnoSetup. On Windows, it is built using mingw. My program is currently distributed for 32-bit Linux and 32-bit Windows, but I would like to add 64-bit Linux as well.

My build platform is Ubuntu 64-bit but I would like to support building on Linux 32-bit as well. The project is also built on Travis CI, which provides virtual build machines made of Ubuntu 32-bit.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Nothing yet. But I hope to get some hints (not necessarily complete solutions) on how to separate to 2 build folders, perform 2 builds, have same binary names for 32-bit and 64-bit builds, and how to detect the current platform type on CMake, then I can get started.

Comment: Make the 64bit and the 32bit build separate builds (i.e. don't try to build both in one go), use CPack for the packaging, and automate all that with Jenkins, Buildbot etc.

Comment: How do I do this? With chroot?

Comment: No just build in a different folder for each different type of build. You have to run cmake-gui and specify a different build folder with the same source folder.

Comment: And add a parameter to force 32-bit build on a 64-bit system for one of the times?

Comment: I mainly use visual studio with different build trees for x64 and 32bit and also different trees for each compiler version. In my case I use a different CMake generator for 64 bit. I know makefiles do not have a separate generator so I do believe the -m 32 param to gcc would do this but I am not sure if that is all..

Comment: Unfortunately I ran into a problem. sqlite is only available in either 32-bit or 64-bit at a time using apt-get and not both simultaneously. So I can't build a 32-bit app using sqlite:i386 on 64-bit Ubuntu machine. Should I ask this as another question?

Comment: take the source code of sqlite and compile in your cmake and then link it. I'm also using it in this way.